# Is there an easy way to INSERT an row when not exists? otherwise give an error using a single MySql query?

Tags: mysql

I am inserting the details of the user into Database and my requirment is to insert the record of the user only is it not exist.If the `name` and `postcode` already exist then pormpt the user that `"record already exist with the same name or post code"` .

here is the Insert query 
`"INSERT INTO sender_list (sender_serial_number , sender_name ,sender_address_id)
                    VALUES  ('$sender_serial_number' , '$sender_name' ,  '$sender_post_code')"`

Comment: add `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Unique Key for the name ? its a text

Comment: And you don't want to create unique indexes on text columns because...?

Comment: i already have a unique on in the ID feild.If i want top make the sender name unique its giving error as `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'fdas' for key 'name'`

Comment: And having already a unique index on some other column is a problem because...?

Comment: because of the error i type

Comment: This is what the unique constraint is designed for. You add it to all fields which need to be unique. If you need a combination of fields to be unique (no 2 people with the same username and postcode) you can add a single constraint to multiple fields. The alternative is to put a write lock on the table, check if the value exists, insert and then release the lock - but it's more work, more error-prone, not enforced by the database and has no real benefit over using the appropriate constraint.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table, check for mysql_errno() in PHP after your INSERT operation. `if(mysql_errno() !== 0)` then there is an error beacuse that record already exists.